# Add a JLabel on key press

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, keylistener

I have a simple `JFrame` that implements a `KeyListener`. I want to add a label when the user type the letter A. When I do so The label doesn't appear directly. When I resize the frame it appear. But it is not the purpose to resize the frame. I want it to appear directly.

How to add a `JLabel` on key press?

Comment: what did you try? show us some code

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

How about calling validate()?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate()

Comment: You should call revalidate() when using Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to call the repaint() function to make it appear directly.